# is it possible to have a nfc read and write with only my app?

Tags: nfc

basically I am getting an app developed that will allow user to write the NFC Tag
but I want the tag to be written only by my application that would be available for download , and not any other free app on play store / App Store

so when the user received the tag from me , he needs to download my app to write it , and then it is ready for use , readability should be universal , any nfc enabled device , should be able to read it

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution for this is, you have to pre-personalize the nfc tags by making write operation password protected with your choice of password. So, only your app can write as you will be knowing the password. Also, read will be available without any effect.